# how to change a preview for html5 video?

Tags: html, video

how to change a preview for html5 video?
I need to show custom image, when user clicks on it video is playing.

```
<video controls="controls">
<source src="1.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add poster attribut to video tag...

```
<video controls="controls" poster="url_to_img.jpg">
<source src="1.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

to set the preview of the HTML5 video you must know about poster attribute in video tag. 
So it should look something like this

```
<video width=blah height=blah poster=blah >
```